# a committee of 3 is to be formed from 6 men and 4 women.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of 3 is to be formed from 6 men and 4 women

1. How many ways can a committee of 3 be formed?
2. How many ways can a committee of 3 men be formed?
3. what is the probability that the committee is made up of  only men?
4. how many can a committee of 2 men and 1 women be formed?
5. what is the probability that the committee is made up of 2 men and 1 woman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) 3 of 10 is ${10 \choose 3}=\frac{10.9.8}{3.2.1}=10.3.4=120$.

B) 3 of 6 is ${6 \choose 3}=\frac{6.5.4}{3.2.1}=5.4=20$.

C) The probability that a committee is of 3 men is 20/120=1/6.

D) Two men and one woman can be chosen in ${6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}=\frac{6.5}
{2.1}\frac{4}{1}=15.4=60$.

E) The probability is 60/120=1/2.